# How can I implement Function and BiFunction at the same time?

Tags: java, function, inheritance, interface, java-8

I created a class `GenericFunction` that implements `Function` and `BiFunction`.  But it cannot be compiled.

```
public class GenericFunction<T, U, R> implements
        Function<T, R>, BiFunction<T, U, R> {

    @Override
    public R apply(T t, U u) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public R apply(T t) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The error message is:

```
src\obscure\test\GenericFunction.java:6: error:
types BiFunction<T,U,R> and Function<T,R> are incompatible;
both define andThen(java.util.function.Function<? super R,? extends V>),
but with unrelated return types
public class GenericFunction<T, U, R> implements
       ^
where T,U,R are type-variables:
  T extends Object declared in class GenericFunction
  U extends Object declared in class GenericFunction
  R extends Object declared in class GenericFunction

1 error
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I would use it with Lambda expression :)

Comment: More importantly: why would you do that?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I am implementing a Lisp interpreter.  This class is lambda function in lisp.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `types BiFunction<T,U,R> and Function<T,R> are incompatible`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extending from [@romacafe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34671028/525036), one thing that I don't like about it is that `GenericFunctionAndThen` extends `GenericFunction` without reusing any of the behaviour of its super class – which looks to me as a bad smell.

Things will be cleaner if you implemented `GenericFunction` as an interface instead:

```
public interface GenericFunction<T, U, R> extends Function<T, R>, BiFunction<T, U, R> {
    @Override
    default <V> GenericFunction<T, U, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        return new GenericFunction<T, U, V>() {
            @Override
            public V apply(final T t, final U u) {
                return after.apply(GenericFunction.this.apply(t, u));
            }

            @Override
            public V apply(final T t) {
                return after.apply(GenericFunction.this.apply(t));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This way you have a simple implementation of the generic behaviour (the `andThen` method), and you can implement your specific behaviour (the 2 `apply` methods) in a specific class without relying on inheritance.

Answer (score 8):

I have no idea why you would want something like this, but it seemed like an interesting challenge...

The main problem is that both Function & BiFunction implement a default `andThen` function, both having the exact same signature, so your class doesn't know which to call.  You just have to provide your own implementation, then its not ambiguous anymore.  However the implementation is tricky.

The java docs say the method:

> Returns a composed function that first applies this function to its input, and then applies the after function to the result.

... so that means returning a new GenericFunction, where both apply methods are now compositions.

I give you this monstrosity:

```
public class GenericFunction<T, U, R> implements Function<T, R>, BiFunction<T, U, R> {

    @Override
    public R apply(T t, U u) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public R apply(T t) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <V> GenericFunction<T, U, V>  andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        return new GenericFunctionAndThen<>(after);
    }

    private class GenericFunctionAndThen<V> extends GenericFunction<T, U, V> {
        private final Function<? super R, ? extends V> after;

        public GenericFunctionAndThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
            this.after = after;
        }

        @Override
        public V apply(T t) {
            return after.apply(GenericFunction.this.apply(t));
        }

        @Override
        public V apply(T t, U u) {
            return after.apply(GenericFunction.this.apply(t, u));
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the most obscure feature of Java that I know of...  I don't even know the name!  `ClassName.this` is used in a nested class to refer to a method (or field) in the enclosing instance, if the method is [shadowed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html#shadowing).

Comment: Sure!  This is the craziest Java I've written in a long time, maybe ever.  Its still clean but also... nuts.  You're writing a Lisp interpreter?  You've heard of Clojure, right?  :)

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to write something like ```(((Stream of 1 2 3) map (lambda (x) (* x x))) toArray)```.